# how event logs are stored

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am working write now to get events, using WMI.

i tried to get the event using the where clause as
`WHERE LogFile='Security' AND EVENTIDENTIFIER='someevent'`

what difference does it make, it i try with
`WHERE EVENTIDENTIFIER='someevent'`

which is good to use and why.?

Thanks,

Comment: Please proofread your questions before you click the submit button. This is unintelligible.

Comment: @Sandeep I tried to fix your formatting.  Please correct it if I messed up the syntax you were intending to enter.

Answer (score 1):

In the former case you are explicitly filtering by Log Type (Security) and an Event ID. In the latter case you are just filtering by Event ID, which obviously does not have to be unique among different log types. But since you are not filtering by Event Source as well, your results are going to be ambiguous in both cases.

Comment: if i am not wrong, event ids are unique for event type, so is there any chance that there can be one event id for two different kind of events in different log file.?

Comment: @sandeep Event IDs are not unique: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/etw/thread/172a0f50-8867-4a53-946d-f6070b9ca081